# How to update django model through data in foreignkey fields?

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to migrate some data from one table to another, and I have the following script:

```
def forward_func(apps, schema_editor):
    targetModel = apps.get_model("target", "some_target")
    targetModel.objects.all().update(a='other__table__a')
```

both fields are boolean, and the data inside the original table has no problem and has correct type.

For some reason, I'm getting this message:

```
ValidationError: [u"'other__table__a' value must be either True or False."]
```

From the django doc (v1.11), I can't really find a topic talking directly about this, but I've found

> However, unlike F() objects in filter and exclude clauses, you can’t introduce joins when you use F() objects in an update – you can only reference fields local to the model being updated. If you attempt to introduce a join with an F() object, a FieldError will be raised:
>
> ```
>    # This will raise a FieldError
>    >>> Entry.objects.update(headline=F('blog__name'))
> ```

Does that mean I simply cannot call `.update` using foreinkeys? Do I have to loop through every object and update this way?

Comment: You're trying to set the field to the literal string "other__table__a".

Comment: @DanielRoseman Is that the case? What's the correct syntax?

Comment: Well normally you would use `F()`. But as that warning you quote states, that doesn't work across joins.